# Implementing 3Legged Authentication with React

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Is there a way to get an example of implementing the 3 legged authentication process in React without using Redux?

The boiler plate is just way complicated for the majority and I guess is good to have something more simple for "the rest of us".

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

To persist Redux states I can think of two options off the top of my head:

- Open a new window session for the authentication and you can close the window and notify the parent window since they'd in the same domain once the callback arrives
- Or persist all essential states to localStorage/sessionStorage to load back after direction

Although we don't exactly have a React sample to generate 3 legged tokens but the that very process has no more to do with your backend - you'd not want to generate a 3 legged token in your front end for security reasons.

So far as React or any front end framework is concerned it's a matter of redirecting the user to sign in to their Autodesk account and set up the callback handler in your backend properly to receive the access code - see our [official tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/oauth/3legged/) for details and there's sample code for both front (albeit in vanialla JS) and back ends

Feel free to comment if you have any specific question re this process.

Comment: Perfectly right, my process is completely managed in the backend using ASP.NET Core. My only concern is that I am loosing the state of the application probably due to a routing issue.